# Can't send XML via HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have the following HTTParty call:

```
HTTParty.post(Yapstone.url, body: person.request_xml)
```

From the API I'm calling I only get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <code>E1036</code>
    <description>No XML was received. Please try again</description>
</Error>
```

I believe this response can only be evoked by sending *nothing*. If I send "asdf" I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <code>E1000</code>
    <description>Invalid XML</description>
</Error>
```

I know `person.request_xml` is fine because even if I hard-code XML in the `HTTParty` call I get the "No XML was received" error.

What am I doing wrong?